# Operation between rows for different columns in a stacked group data frame

Tags: r

R experts,

I have a stacked data frame and I want to create new columns based on conditional operation between rows which will be applied to different groups in data frame. I have a simple case to try out at your end.

```
df<-data.frame(case=c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6)),
               cond=c(rep(1:6),rep(1:6)),
               param1=c(100,200,300,400,500,600,150,250,350,450,550,650),
               param2=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,10,20,30,40,50,60))
```

Here is what I want the function to achieve -

(1) I want to create new columns (for eg. dparam1 and dparam2) based on param1 and param2. dparam1 is basically ratio of param1 at given "cond" normalized by param1@cond=6. Basically for each group, all rows are divided by one particular row.

Resultant data frame with new columns will look like this -

```
dfnew<-data.frame(case=c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6)),
               cond=c(rep(1:6),rep(1:6)),
               param1=c(100,200,300,400,500,600,150,250,350,450,550,650),
               param2=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,10,20,30,40,50,60),
               dparam1=c(0.17,0.33,0.5,0.67,0.83,1.0,0.17,0.33,0.5,0.67,0.83,1.0),
               dparam2=c(0.17,0.33,0.5,0.67,0.83,1.0,0.23,0.38,0.54,0.69,0.85,1.0))
```

(2) I do not want to specify name of new column. New columns should be named as "d" followed by original column name. I think I will have to use paste function (I am not sure!). But I am interested in seeing your inputs.

(3) Finally, I want to provide list of column names for which I want normalized new columns as an argument to this new function.

Here is my current function -

```
param_list<-c("param1","param2")
condref<-6
fun <- function(x,list) {
for (i in list) {
if(grepl("param1|param2",i)){
x$paste(c("d",i),collapse='')<-x$i/x$i[x$cond==condref]}
else{x$paste(c("d",i),collapse='')<-x$i-x$i[x$cond==condref]}
}
x
}

dfnew<-fun(df,param_list)

And the error - 
Error in x$paste(c("d", i), collapse = "") <- x$i - x$i[x$cond == condref] : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have the desired output and a series of conditions that the code needs to meet. Where's your code do to that? Where are you stuck?

Comment: How is it not working? Is there an error? What's the difference between the observed and expected behaviors? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here is my current function - 

param_list<-c("param1","param2")
condref<-6
fun <- function(x,list) {
for (i in list) {
if(grepl("param1|param2",i)){
x$paste(c("d",i),collapse='')<-x$i/x$i[x$cond==condref]}
else{x$paste(c("d",i),collapse='')<-x$i-x$i[x$cond==condref]}
}
x
}

dfnew<-fun(df,param_list)

And the error - 
Error in x$paste(c("d", i), collapse = "") <- x$i - x$i[x$cond == condref] : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object

Comment: Super! Could you edit that into the question, please? That way other users can quickly see it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have a solution, but damn is it ugly:

```
maxCond <- as.data.frame(t(unstack(aggregate(cond~case,df,max),cond~case)));
cbind(df,setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(df$case), function(case) do.call(cbind,lapply(c('param1','param2'), function(col) round(df[df$case==case,col]/df[df$case==case&df$cond==maxCond[[case]],col],2) ))))),paste0('d',c('param1','param2'))));
##    case cond param1 param2 dparam1 dparam2
## 1     A    1    100     10    0.17    0.17
## 2     A    2    200     20    0.33    0.33
## 3     A    3    300     30    0.50    0.50
## 4     A    4    400     40    0.67    0.67
## 5     A    5    500     50    0.83    0.83
## 6     A    6    600     60    1.00    1.00
## 7     B    1    150     10    0.23    0.17
## 8     B    2    250     20    0.38    0.33
## 9     B    3    350     30    0.54    0.50
## 10    B    4    450     40    0.69    0.67
## 11    B    5    550     50    0.85    0.83
## 12    B    6    650     60    1.00    1.00
```

You can wrap it in a function as follows:

```
f <- function(df,cols) { maxCond <- as.data.frame(t(unstack(aggregate(cond~case,df,max),cond~case))); cbind(df,setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(df$case), function(case) do.call(cbind,lapply(cols, function(col) round(df[df$case==case,col]/df[df$case==case&df$cond==maxCond[[case]],col],2) ))))),paste0('d',cols))); };
f(df,c('param1','param2'));
## same result as above
```

Comment: Actually, @user3693111, our outputs seem to have mixed up `dparam1` and `dparam2` for case B. I'm pretty sure my result is correct; for example, 150/650 should give 0.23 in `dparam1`, no? Your `dfnew` has 0.17 there. Please confirm whether my output is correct, or whether yours is.

Comment: @bgoldst...Thanks for sharing your code. Your output is correct.

Comment: Any other ideas guys?